# How to correctly create the vertices for this type of wiresphere?

Tags: c#, geometry, rendering, directx-11

I'm currently trying to create a wiresphere that looks like this:[image]

I came up with code that looks like this:

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace VoidwalkerEngine.Framework.DirectX.Rendering
{
    public static class Wireframe
    {
        public static ModelMesh GenerateWireframeSphere(Device device, Vector3 location, float radius)
        {
            float pi = (float)Math.PI;
            List<Vertex> vertices = new List<Vertex>();
            float twoPi = 2 * pi;
            float angleStep = twoPi / 16f;
            for (float angle = 0f; angle <= twoPi; angle += angleStep)
            {
                float x = radius * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
                float y = radius * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
                float z = 0;
                vertices.Add(new Vertex(location.X + x, location.Y + y, location.Z + z));
            }
            for (float angle = 0f; angle <= twoPi; angle += angleStep)
            {
                float x = radius * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
                float y = 0;
                float z = radius * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
                vertices.Add(new Vertex(location.X + x, location.Y + y, location.Z + z));
            }
            for (float angle = 0f; angle <= twoPi; angle += angleStep)
            {
                float x = 0;
                float y = radius * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
                float z = radius * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
                vertices.Add(new Vertex(location.X + x, location.Y + y, location.Z + z));
            }
            ModelMesh mesh = new ModelMesh(device, vertices.ToArray());
            return mesh;
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in a sphere that looks like this (Using LineStrip):
[image]

As you can see, the circles are not complete, and not only that, but there is an extra line connecting the top ring to the middle ring. I feel as though this is actually a side effect of using LineStrip. If I use LineList instead, my code results in this:

[image]

Much better, But I'm missing segments. LineList is clearly the way to go, but I don't know how to correctly update my code to add in those missing line segments. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I figured out what i was doing wrong. I'm currently in the process of doing a full rewrite. Once i complete it, I'll upload it here as an answer. I had the big dumb.

Comment: While not for C#, the logic here is the same as the sphere in [DebugDraw](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DebugDraw).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Hey, thanks for dropping a comment. The issue that I was having, was that I, for some reason, forgot that I needed to chain each vertex to the one before it. Basically, I need to inject a duplicate vertex after every vertex past the zero index of each loop. That solves the problem. I also needed to "bite the tail" at the end of each loop; basically have the last index loop back to the 0 index. I'll have a coding sample up here in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. And the answer is that I was being rather dumb. I forgot that I needed to chain the vertices together, as well as loop back around and "bite the tail" of each ring. Here is the solution:

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using System;

namespace VoidwalkerEngine.Framework.DirectX.Rendering
{
    public static class Wireframe
    {
        public static ModelMesh GenerateWireframeSphere(Device device, Vector3 location, float radius)
        {
            float pi = (float)Math.PI;
            Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[96];
            float twoPi = 2 * pi;
            float angleStep = twoPi / 16f;
            int iterator = 0;
            /**
             * 1st Ring
             */
            int firstIndex = 0;
            for (float angle = 0f; angle <= twoPi; angle += angleStep)
            {
                if (iterator > firstIndex + 1)
                {
                    vertices[iterator] = vertices[iterator++ - 1];
                }
                float x = radius * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
                float y = radius * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
                float z = 0;
                vertices[iterator++] = new Vertex(location.X + x, location.Y + y, location.Z + z);
            }
            vertices[iterator] = vertices[iterator++ - 1];
            vertices[iterator++] = vertices[firstIndex];
            /**
             * 2nd Ring
             */
            firstIndex = iterator;
            for (float angle = 0f; angle <= twoPi; angle += angleStep)
            {
                if (iterator > firstIndex + 1)
                {
                    vertices[iterator] = vertices[iterator++ - 1];
                }
                float x = radius * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
                float y = 0;
                float z = radius * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
                vertices[iterator++] = new Vertex(location.X + x, location.Y + y, location.Z + z);
            }
            vertices[iterator] = vertices[iterator++ - 1];
            vertices[iterator++] = vertices[firstIndex];
            /**
             * 3rd Ring
             */
            firstIndex = iterator;
            for (float angle = 0f; angle <= twoPi; angle += angleStep)
            {
                if (iterator > firstIndex + 1)
                {
                    vertices[iterator] = vertices[iterator++ - 1];
                }
                float x = 0;
                float y = radius * (float)Math.Sin(angle);
                float z = radius * (float)Math.Cos(angle);
                vertices[iterator++] = new Vertex(location.X + x, location.Y + y, location.Z + z);
            }
            vertices[iterator] = vertices[iterator++ - 1];
            vertices[iterator++] = vertices[firstIndex];
            return new ModelMesh(device, vertices);
        }
    }
}
```

And an image that shows the result:
[image]

It should be noted that the resolution of this sphere is static, because in the sample above, I did not calculate a dynamic resolution based upon size. Doing that would also need to resize the array. So if you end up using this, be mindful of the limitation, switch to a list instead of an array, or achieve the small amount of work you will have to do to add dynamic resolution.